# how to adapt this website for smaller devices via media

Tags: css, containers, responsive, media

Hi My website is not being responsive on smaller devices. I tried to use @media in my code but that doesn't work so I don't really knwo what to do next any help.

my css code:

```
 /* Základní styly pro navbar */
 .navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* Styly pro odkazy v navbaru */
.navbar a {
  float: left ;
  color: white;
  text-align:left ;
  padding: 10px 126.7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  text-size-adjust: center;
  line-height: 70px;
  transform: rotate(-10);
}
/* Styly pro odkazy při najetí myší */
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
.container{
  background:linear-gradient(45deg, blueviolet, lightgreen);
  padding:15px 9%;
  padding-top: 20px; 
}
.container .card-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap:15px;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  padding: 50px;
}
.container .card-container .card{
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 450px;
  height: 600px;
  border-style: solid;
 padding-top: 35px; 
}
.container .card-container .card:nth-child(1){
background: #333;
} 
.container .card-container .card:first-child h1:first-child{ 
  color: white;
}
.container .card-container .card:first-child h3{ 
  color: white;
}
h1:nth-of-type(2){ 
  color: chocolate;
}
h1{  
  display: inline;
  margin: 15px;
  margin-left: 50px;
margin-right: 50px; 
}
.container .card-container .card .text{
padding-top: 45px;
font-size: 1em ;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-right: 50px;
}
.container .card-container .card:first-child .text{
  padding-top: 45px;
  font-size: 1em ;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  color: white; 
  }
h3{
  margin-left: 50px;
margin-right: 50px; 
  text-align: left; 
}
.container .card-container .card:first-child h2:nth-of-type(1){ 
  color: white;
}
h2{
  display: inline; 
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 50px;
margin-right: 50px;
}
h2:nth-of-type(2){
  
  color: chocolate;
}
@media (max-width:768px){
  .container{
      padding:20px;
  }
}
```

I
tried to write some media forms but that doesn't work, its not responsive, if anyone know what to do else. I dont know what should I write more so I am just typing some things.

Comment: you need to re-write all `class `or `id` CSS properties again in `media` for those you want to change.

Comment: What exactly do you want to update on mobile screen of your web page? Because the media that you've added will only update padding on the container of your web page for mobile view.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try writing media queries like this: (It will take effect from 768px screen width and below that)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .container{
      padding:20px;
    }
    
    //Try with the rest of your selectors and make the changes within these curly brackets.
}
```

If you want to make changes from another smaller screen size then you can again write another media query like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    //Write your codes (It will take effect from 500px screen width and below that)
}
```

If you want to show all the cards in a single column (one in each row) then I think this will do it:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .container .card-container{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}
```

You may need to make some other adjustments.

Comment: I just want that every card will be under in one column when I tried to  change the window it doesn't work

Comment: OK, I updated it in my answer.

Comment: thanks I already tried this once but didn't work but somehow it works now maybe I did name some wrong path i think that I jsut name container but no card-container. Anyway thanks